# Why are Imperial Credits worthless in the Mandalorian?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

In the first episode of the Mandalorian, Mando (or someone else) refuses to accept Imperial credits as a payment as they are worthless. As this is set just after the fall of the Empire, why are Imperial credits already worthless?

Surely the New Republic wouldn't have had time to replace an entire currency, and credits would be just credits afterall. Surely some kind of financial/economic stability would be needed?

Is there a reason for this? Indeed in real life is it common for this to happen?

I can understand when one country invades enough they might switch to the invading countries currency if they "swallowed" the loser. But in this case, the rebellion weren't exactly another state

Comment: At this point in the timeline, people don't really know *what's* going to happen. Better to stick with the currency from a viable state than one that might be on the verge of failing.

Comment: My point really was, how would the republic have had time to create a new currency, when the credits would still have served an economic purpose and most likely have been wide spread

Comment: Imperial credits are worthless when there's no Empire. All that's left is the Remnant, which barely has any control, and whoever got to the Unknown Regions. It's also been 4 years since the New Republic seized control of the galaxy, plenty of time to set up its own currency. The New Republic probably moved away from anything Imperial as fast as they possibly could, they probably wouldn't want their government to be related to the Empire in any way.

Comment: Interested to know why someone downvoted this or if I could have expanded the question some how

Comment: I am re-watching the series and I thought about this question.  He doesn't like droids, probably because super battle droids killed his family, and he doesn't deal with them.  He and the other Mandalorians in his clan really don't like the empire.  Maybe he just would rather take a pay cut than deal with Imperial currency he can't melt down and make into armor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, *The Mandalorian* takes place [five years](https://www.vulture.com/2019/11/the-mandalorian-timeline.html) after the Return of the Jedi. That's probably more than enough time for even a fledgling Republic to get its own currency off-the-ground. For historical comparison, it took about [four years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palestine_pound) for Israel to adopt its own currency without Spaaaaaace! technology.

But the [dialogue](https://transcripts.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_1:_The_Mandalorian) ALSO suggests that the credits still have *some* value, it's just a decision by the individual character not to accept it:

> Din Djarin: These are Imperial Credits.
>
> **Greef Karga: They still spend.**
>
> Din Djarin: I don't know if you heard, but the Empire is gone.

So you're probably right that there's probably still people trading with Imperial credits. But there are still those who would prefer not to be paid in a currency with such low stability and waning use. How would you feel if someone tried to pay you in Venezuelan bolivars?

It's also worth noting that in *Phantom Menace* we see that Republic credits are considered worthless in Tatooine, and this was when it was the sole galactic power. So there's precedent for the galaxy's seedy elements shying away from even widely adopted currency.

Answer (score 3):

**The only Imperials left are holdouts of a failed state.**

Five years after the battle of Endor, and right after the battle of Jakku, the Empire surrendered and signed the Galactic Concordance:

> Under the terms of the Instruments of Surrender, the Empire was ordered to cease fighting and called for the **final disbandment of Palpatine era government**, faciliting Amedda stepping down as head of the Empire. Mothma also signed a further declaration classifying all surviving Imperial officers who did not adhere to the terms of surrender as war criminals. However, non-combatant functionaries including Amedda were granted conditional pardons. Under the terms of surrender, the Imperial remnant was also compelled to accede to the demands of the Galactic Concordance, including a ban on the recruitment and mobilization of stormtroopers, the abandonment of the galactic-wide network of Imperial Academies, the surrender of Coruscant to the New Republic, and the confinement of the remaining Imperial Navy to predetermined boundaries in the Core and Inner Rim.
>
> ...
>
> Some remaining Imperials refused to adhere to the terms of surrender as was done in the Core Worlds. These Imperial hardliners organized themselves into a separate remnant. While the conflict was never officially reignited, a cold war broke out between those factions. Later, these holdouts would to relocate to the Unknown Regions...
>
> [Galactic Concordance](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Galactic_Concordance)

The New Republic may only be a fledgling state at this point, but the Imperial Remnant has almost no influence at this point in the timeline. Thus, no one is going to trust their currency.

Comment: To be fair, the only Imperial-aligned world that we see affected by Operation: Cinder was Vardos, and even then there was authorization to extract certain individuals necessary for the continuation of the Empire. One might argue that it was the ultimate test of loyalty to see if an Imperial Admiral (especially an ISB officer) would willingly devastate his own homeworld in the name of his Emperor.

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 Arg, I could argue about this, but it's really off-topic, I'm just gonna remove the bit about Cinder.

Comment: I can delete my comment if you'd like. Sorry to be a bother.

Answer (score 2):

If currency isn't backed by precious metal it's backed by guarantee, debt or some sort of mutual credit assurance. Post-Endor, the Empire has fallen to dissolution and it's currency is backed or accepted in Empire controlled worlds, Bounty hunters and vagabonds of the galaxy don't travel to Imperial worlds much except to conduct their illicit/questionable affairs so another source of payment is needed. In Star Wars series various characters, groups don't accept legitimate government currency, especially electronic payment for fear of reprisal, denial or tracking or it's inherited value in backwater worlds or lack of legal bank/accounts. Instead preferring to be paid in valuable commodity (Spice, precious metal, jewels, Beskar, etc), an accepted currency in a jurisdiction they frequent, Live.